# Is it possible to restrict values for a column in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

is it possible to restrict what values are allowed for a column in informatica. For eg, there is a column called Item_number, for which I want values to be in range of 1 to 10, is it possible to implement that, if so which transformation I can use for that?

Comment: Please, provide some code with things you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `FILTER` transformation. In properties you can mention -

```
Item_number >=1 AND Item_number <=10
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. Will use this

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a lookup transformation in your mapping and that lookup can be a flat file or table depending on your requirement.
Keep the valid values in that lookup file/table and verify the input data for that column.
If lookup returns a value, the data is valid; else incorrect data in case null is returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the data in your column without removing any rows, use a simple function combination:

```
IIF(in_val>10, 10, IIF(in_val<1, 1, in_val))
```

Check if that works fine with your scenario - come back if you need further help.